# Exception when "spark-shell --master yarn-client"

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, apache-spark-sql

When I run

```
spark-shell --master yarn-client
```

An error occurs as follows:

```
14/12/23 12:06:33 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at main/10.20.236.201:8032
    14/12/23 12:06:33 INFO yarn.Client: Got cluster metric info from ResourceManager, number of NodeManagers: 2
    14/12/23 12:06:33 INFO yarn.Client: Max mem capabililty of a single resource in this cluster 2048
    14/12/23 12:06:33 INFO yarn.Client: Preparing Local resources
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from an empty string
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.checkPathArg(Path.java:127)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:135)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:94)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ClientBase$class.copyRemoteFile(ClientBase.scala:159)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.copyRemoteFile(Client.scala:37)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ClientBase$$anonfun$prepareLocalResources$5$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ClientBase.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ClientBase$$anonfun$prepareLocalResources$5$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ClientBase.scala:231)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ClientBase$$anonfun$prepareLocalResources$5.apply(ClientBase.scala:231)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ClientBase$$anonfun$prepareLocalResources$5.apply(ClientBase.scala:229)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ClientBase$class.prepareLocalResources(ClientBase.scala:229)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.prepareLocalResources(Client.scala:37)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.runApp(Client.scala:74)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:92)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:333)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.createSparkContext(SparkILoop.scala:981)
        at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:8)
        at $iwC.<init>(<console>:14)
        at <init>(<console>:16)
        at .<init>(<console>:20)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at .<init>(<console>:7)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at $print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:789)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1062)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:615)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:646)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:610)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:823)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:868)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:780)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.beQuietDuring(SparkIMain.scala:264)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.initializeSpark(SparkILoopInit.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$5.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:940)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.runThunks(SparkILoopInit.scala:142)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.runThunks(SparkILoop.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.postInitialization(SparkILoopInit.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.postInitialization(SparkILoop.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:957)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:911)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:911)
        at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:911)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1006)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:329)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

This part of the error stands out:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from an empty string
```

How can I troubleshoot this error?

Comment: Please tell us what you are trying to do so that we can identify why the error was produced and what you should do instead.

Comment: I just want to run spark-shell in yarn-client mode

Comment: Is the path having a space init?

Comment: @Vijay I guess there is a configuration property need a path to init, but i don't know which is the property.Can you help me to find it out?